# Access website without adding Google DNS

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a question about How to configure server so that customers can access to my website without adding Google DNS 8.8.8.8. As you know, if customers don't add Google DNS, they can't access my website. It's like my website can't resolved.

Comment: `As you know, if customers don't add Google DNS, they can't access my website.` - Do we know that? Why would we know that? Why would this scenario exist?

Comment: Sorry I don't get it.

Comment: I tested my website with a different network without Google Open DNS 8.8.8.8 and I couldn't access my website. It just stated "safari cannot open the page...". Once I added the Google DNS 8.8.8.8 to my wifi network, I could open it then.

Comment: Give us the domain name so we can take a look.

Answer (score 3):

Your customer should add *any* DNS, not only one of Google's, to be able to reach your site. Consult your Internet access provider about which DNSs you should use.

Comment: Of course, supposing that your server has a FQDN in a public DNS server.

Comment: Since most of my customers are old. They don't know how to add any DNS. They used the default DNS from routers. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: @KevinNguyen As long as your customers are using a properly-configured DNS resolver (which I assume they are, if their ISP has configured things well), then that's all they'll need. If the don't have a proper resolver, they wouldn't be able to *anything* on the internet.